# Getting error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type C++

Tags: c++, sorting, types, new-operator, file-io

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I used the same code previously and it gave me no problem, but now for some reason im getting an error.

```
            outputf3 << "The sorted list is as follows: \n\n";
            sorting = new float [function.sort()]; // Here is where the error is.
            for (i=0; i < length ; i ++)            
            {
            outputf2 << "\n" << sorting[i] ;
            }
```

For some reason it's saying
`error: expression in new-declarator must have integral or enumeration type`

But i used the same thing here in a previous part of the program.

```
           inputs = new float[length];
           inputf.clear();
           inputf.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
```

I have no idea why it's doing this at all. 
What I'm doing is reading random numbers in from a file and then sorting them in another part of the function and writeing them out to the output file.

Comment: What is `function.sort()`? What is its return value?

Comment: if `function.sort()` doesn't return an integer type ... the error is normal

Comment: `float DSP1D::sort()
{
   int i=0;
   int x=0;
   
 for (i=length; i>=0; i--)
 {
 for (x=0; x<length-1; x++)
  {
  if (inputs[x] > inputs[x+1])
   {
    float temp = inputs[x+1];
    inputs[x+1] = inputs[x];
    inputs[x] = temp;
   }
  }
 }
 return *inputs;
    
}`

Is the function.sort, it retuns the inputs and is of type float

Comment: @TyberiusSeppala it needs to be of integral type. But even then, it wouldn't make sense. You need to return the size of `inputs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you think:

```
inputs = new float[length];
```

is the same as

```
sorting = new float [function.sort()];
```

?

Unless `function` is a class instance and `sort` returns an integral type, it's certain it won't work.

The statement:

```
Type* t = new Type[x];
```

dynamically allocates `x` objects of type `Type`. It's fairly obvious why `x` has to be of integral type.

EDIT: As per your comment:

The size to be allocated **needs to be of integral type**, but you return a `float`. But even then, it wouldn't make sense. You need to return the size of `inputs`.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.
So my return value for the `function.sort()` is `inputs`

and `inputs` needs to be the same type as float, right? 
Which it is earlier stated in my program to be

Comment: @TyberiusSeppala float is not an integral type.

Comment: So then I can't use `new` with this at all?

Comment: @TyberiusSeppala the way you have it, no. If you want to use new like this, you have to return an `int` from the sort method, and return the length of the array.

Answer (score -1):

i'm gonna go out on a limb and say function.sort() returns void. meaning this line:

```
sorting = new float [function.sort()];
```

is the same as writing...

```
sorting = new float [void];
```

which doesn't make any sense. you probably want the length of whatever function.sort() is working on?

Comment: Don't go out on a limb. Ask the OP a question in a comment.

Comment: I was being facetious. I've never seen a sort method with anything other than a void signature.